# If value is greater/lesser than xyz

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a value as a number. For instance, 502.
I want to write a php if statement that will display some text if the value is lesser or greater than certain numbers, or between a range.

E.g.
number is 502, text will say: "Between 500-600"
number is 56, text will say: "Between 0-60"
etc.

So far I have this:

```
<?php $count=0;?>
<?php $board = getUserBoard($userDetails['userId']);?>
<?php if(is_array($board)):?>
<?php  $boardCount = count($board);?>
<?php foreach($board as $key=>$value):?>
<?php
$boardPin = getEachBoardPins($value->id);
$count = $count + count($boardPin);
?>
<?php endforeach?>
<?php endif?>
```

And that gives me a number:

```
<?php echo $count;?>
```

I have tried writing...

```
<?php if(($count)): => 500 ?>
Over 500
<?php endif ?>
```

But I keep running into errors.

I'd like to create a list if possible with elseif statements denoting various number ranges.

E.g.

0-50, 51-250, 251-500 etc.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you putting every statement in a different PHP blocks? Are they in different locations inside the file?

Comment: you do know that you don't have to wrap every php command in the <? tags separately, right? the start/end of file is good

Comment: @Pietu, It is the way the script is written. It calls from preset variables defined somewhere else in the script. It is a Pinterest clone.
At dognose, I have tried google but I don't know what keywords to use, which is why I've asked here where I can outline exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The sanest, neatest and most widely used syntax for `if conditions` in PHP is:

```
if($value >=500 && $value <=600 )
{
  echo "value is between 500 and 600";
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
this works for me.

I'm not sure why each line is wrapped in the php tag, it is they way whoever wrote the script decided to do it. I personally find it unnecessary but it is in every file through the script so I've got into the habit and writing like that too.

Comment: You only need to open and close php tags if you are going to have some non-php lines in between. Read more on the basic usage of the script and slowly you will understand it better. One another way is to examine some open source project source, just to see the formatting and usage best practises

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($count >= 0 && $count < 100) {
    echo 'between 0 et 99';
} elseif ($count < 199) {
    echo 'between 100 and 199';
} elseif { ...

}elseif ($count < 599) {
    echo 'between 500 and 599';
} else {
    echo 'greater or equal than 600';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something like this a few years back (might be a better way to do it):

```
function create_range($p_num, $p_group = 1000) {
    $i = 0;

    while($p_num >= $i) {
        $i += $p_group;
    }

    $i -= $p_group;

    return $i . '-' . ($i + $p_group - 1);
}

print 'The number is between ' . create_range(502, 100) . '.';
```

It'll say 500-599, but you can adjust it to your needs.

Comment: What does that have to do with and `if` statement testing if a value is in a range?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  The guy said he wanted something where if the "number is 502, text will say: 'Between 500-600'".  This more or less does that.

Comment: So I just do: `if (create_range(499, 100))` and that will evaluate to false if 499 is not between 500 and 600?

Comment: Of course not, it returns a concatenated string.  There's an example at the bottom.  I'm not sure if you're just trying to be difficult or genuinely do not understand that I've provided an alternate take on the problem.

Comment: No you're correct. That is completely my fault - I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you need, but here is what I understand you ask:

```
function getRange($n, $limit = array(50, 250, 500)) { // Will create the ranges 0-50, 51-250, 251-500 and 500-infinity
  $previousLimit = 0;
  foreach ($limits as $limit) {
    if ($n < $limit) {
      return 'Between ' . ($previousLimit + 1) . ' and ' . $limit; //Return whatever you need.
    }
    $previousLimit = $limit;
  }
  return 'Greater than ' . $previousLimit; // Return whatever you need.
}

echo getRange(56); // Prints "Between 51 and 250"
echo getRange(501); // Prints "Greater than 500"
echo getRange(12, array(5, 10, 15, 20)); // Prints "Between 11 and 15"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRange($number){
    $length=strlen($number);
    $length--;
    $r1=round($number,-$length);
    if ($r1>$number){
        $r2=$r1-pow(10,$length);
    return ''.$number.' value is between '.$r2.'-'.$r1;
    }
    else {
    $r2=$r1+pow(10,$length);
        return  ''.$number.' value is between '.$r1.'-'.$r2;
    }
 }
```

Try this.